# BIOS Secure Boot not available - HP Compaq Elite 8300 with integrated and discrete graphics

Tags: boot, 20.04, graphics, hp, bios

My old HP desktop came with integrated and a discrete Radeon graphics card that I would like to use with Ubuntu 20.04, but when it is installed the screen just goes blank (tried both outputs, integrated and discrete).
On the previous OS, Windows 7, everything ran fine.
I cant' understand why it worked before, as the only action was a format and Ubuntu install, didn't mess with the BIOS settings.

Some [research](https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c03653226#Troubleshooting) pointed to the BIOS Secure Boot feature, it should be disabled. My BIOS does not have that option. Don't know if a BIOS update would help, or if it even is possible to do one from Ubuntu 20.04 (no Windows installed).
Not sure if the Secure Boot option is the only reason why discrete graphics cause this problem.
Doubts aplenty, anyone care to share similar experiences? Thanks.

HP Compaq Elite 8300 Base Model Microtower PC
intel core i7-3770
BIOS v02.05

Comment: Why it worked before is because the OS was signed so there was no reason for Secure Boot to be disabled.  Your system is showing BIOS version 03.08 now.  https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-compaq-elite-8300-microtower-pc/5232859  It is very possible to do it.  You can download the sp95971.exe file and extract all the files out of it.  Then create a DOS boot USB with USB support on it with the DOS Flash folder copied on to it.  There's plenty of README.TXT files in there explaining how to do it.

Comment: Thanks, Did just that but the BIOS update failed after the "Transferring" phase. BIOS did not update. In the meantime found this on a HP.com page.  "note: HP and Compaq Desktop PCs that were manufactured with Windows 7 or earlier _do not have a BIOS version that allows the use of Secure Boot and one will not be made available_ for these computers." so I guess my attemp to update BIOS in hope of getting "Secure Boot", to then disable it and install the graphics card, is useless.

Comment: https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03653226

Comment: In the meantime, found why the BIOS update failed, can't jump straight from my version 2.05 to 3, must do an interim update before to 2.9.

Comment: I guess it can't hurt to do the step updates to see if that opens up new BIOS features.